# What is the differences between docker network drivers?

Tags: docker

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                         DRIVER              SCOPE
90ed18951aa8        bridge                       bridge              local
02a1158b1219        docker-registry_default      bridge              local
myn3onq0xgdg        ingress                      overlay             swarm
2t91hityplpb        preprod_default              overlay             swarm
```

What is the differences between 'overlay' and 'bridge' drivers? When each of them should be used?

Comment: See the [networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) in the Docker documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `overlay` network is used in swarm mode to create a network that spans multiple docker hosts.  A `bridge` network exists only on a single host (and is realized by a Linux bridge device).

For more information, see the the "[Network Drivers](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)" section of the Docker documentation.